# Pico W asynchronous web server: impossible to disable wifi

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I use this code for an asynchronous web server and it works fine:

https://gist.github.com/aallan/3d45a062f26bc425b22a17ec9c81e3b6

EDIT : This link is my only code, so it's easy to reproduce the issue

Problem is, I cant find a way to disable wlan.

The original code is like that: (in different locations, check code)

```
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
```

So I simply try:

```
wlan.active(False)
```

But the web server is still running and `print(wlan.active())` returns True...

I tried placing it at MANY locations in the asynchronous web server code, but I coudldnt make it work.

I need to disable the wlan entirely from time to time and I cant make it work... spent the whole day on it.

Thank you!

EDIT 2 : More details after testing

```
>>> wlan.active(True)
>>> print(wlan.active())
True # as expected

>>> wlan.active(False)
>>> print(wlan.active())
True # ???

>>> wlan.disconnect()
>>> print(wlan.active())
False # ???
```

`wlan.disconnect()` seems to put the wlan interface down, which should be what `wlan.active(False)` does, and it doesnt even do it in fact, because a simple `wlan.connect(ssid, password)` gets the `wlan.active(True)` again by itself... so it wasnt really False.

Oh and `wlan.active(False)` doest not work, at all. There is no scenario where it has any effect.

If someone could explain me that... Thank you

Comment: According to https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/docs/library/network.WLAN.rst   `.. method:: WLAN.active([is_active])  Activate ("up") or deactivate ("down") network interface, if boolean argument is passed. Otherwise, query current state if no argument is provided. Most other methods require active interface.`  So what you are doing should work.

Comment: Can you update your question to include code that reproduces the problem you're asking about?

Comment: Thank you, the provided link is my only code, so it's easy to reproduce the issue just with that asynchronous web server code

Comment: @larsks

I made a second edit (EDIT 2) to give even more details, thanks a lot

Comment: This is probably an issue specific to the Pico W port of micropython. The only thing `WLAN.active(True)` does is load the driver blob for the wifi chip. You are correct that `WLAN.active(False)` does nothing (on STA_IF, it works as expected on AP_IF).

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish by running a webserver with the network connection down.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and after some experimentation and digging in the code I found the solution. You have to call the (undocumented) `wlan.deinit()` method:

```
def disconnect():
    wlan.disconnect()
    wlan.active(False)
    wlan.deinit()
```

This will deactivate the wifi chip and reduce the power usage of the board accordingly.

Comment: There is no explanation why this works.